# Trying to create Web Service client in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, service, web

I have followed the small tutorial for creating a web service client in eclipse:

http://px.pats.no/px/Eclipse_tutorial.html

However, I relaized that I do not have the following classes which I believe is used to access the web services. I am getting an error message.

import org.csapi.www.schema.parlayx.common.v2_1.PolicyException;
import org.csapi.www.schema.parlayx.terminal_location.v2_2.LocationInfo;
import org.csapi.www.wsdl.parlayx.terminal_location.v3_0.service.TerminalLocation;
import org.csapi.www.wsdl.parlayx.terminal_location.v3_0.service.TerminalLocationServiceLocator;

I would really appreciate any help. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add 2 jars of parlays in your application.
You might be having them already if you are tutorial has mentioned it or alternatively you can download it from :
http://www.findjar.com/index.x;jsessionid=96A5E1162D798BCF3CB77305955A359E?query=parlayx

or [http://www.parlayx.com/][2]

[2]: http://www.parlayx.com/ 
do watch out for versions of jars as package/class names might be different and you will have to change them accordingly

Answer (score 0):

I've found [this tutorial](http://www.craigsprogramming.com/2011/03/tutorial-consume-any-web-service-using.html) useful. It uses Axis for the client.